# Can i create an iOS simulator programatically on demand like in android(emulator)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

In android i can create an emulator with `android create avd` and all the properties i want to have. Is there a way to do this in MacOs/Xcode via commands or can i only address the built-in simulators provided by xcode?
If not, is there a way to start a simulator in MAcOs several times?

Background is automated testing and building an environment on demand.
To be more clear: The need is a cluster of devices(simulator/emulator) to run tests in parallel. So i need to know if there is a way to have multiple simulators running of whatever instance i need.
So when i want to test "iPhone 6" i need to have 10 instances to run my tests parallel to get a fast feedback in an agile continuous delivery background.

I didn't find anything in the internet so i guess the answer is no and no way.

Edit: Would at least be nice to leave a comment when downvoting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do has been supported since Xcode 6 with the `simctl` command.  Take a look at:

```
$ xcrun simctl create
Usage: simctl create <name> <device type id> <runtime id>
```

You can get a list of devicetype ids and runtime ids by running:

`xcrun simctl list devicetypes runtimes`

You can then boot them using `xcrun simctl boot <device UDID>`.  Using Xcode 6.x and 7.x, such boots are limited in scope (can't install and launch apps, but you can spawn processes), but as of more recent Xcode 8 betas, they will boot to full sessions (although you can't interact with them using Simulator.app, they are great for use in automated test and build environments).

Comment: ok, im on my way.., somehow. Got some more questions. What happens if i create a devices under the same name. i figured out that it gives me another UUID. Also when i try to boot it does not appear. When i try to boot the same in the consloe again it gives me : xcrun simctl boot 84712E71-8D64-4C82-8E9C-5181D4C32B7C
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Unable to boot device in current state: Booted  ...., saying it is booted, but not shown

Comment: I can shutdown it and boot it again, but nothing shows up. Is that the defined behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "shows up"?  Do you expect it to be appearing in Simulator.app?  That's not quite how it works.  The devices are booted and you can interact with them in a purely headless sense (you can spawn processes, install apps, launch apps, run your tests, etc, but you can't interact with it on the screen).  This is designed to be used in a test center with automated testing and no head.  If you need to interact with it, you are limited to just one in Simulator.app for now (but you can spawn multiple instances of Simulator.app if needed).

Comment: Ahh, ok. This is also ok for me. So i guess to make a screenshot of this headless simulator is not possible, right?

Comment: How can i spawn multiple Simulator.app? I tried and also EricS tried to but it lead to error

Comment: Right, you can't get a screenshot of the headless simulator at present, sorry.  You can just execute the Simulator process multiple times from Terminal.  Each time you execute /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator, you get a new instance of the app.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can only use the simulators provided by Xcode - but that should really be all you need. There are fewer variations in hardware in iOS than Android, so there shouldn't be any settings or properties to apply.

As far as running the Simulator app as much as you want, you can certainly do that. The simulator is an app on your computer just like anything else.

Mine is located here (I also believe this is the default path):

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`

I added my simulator app to my dock so I can launch it anytime (also helps with debugging website layout for mobile devices)

Hope this helps.

EDIT: If you need to open from the command line:

`open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`

will do it

Comment: That means i can run this simulator app multiple times without any restrictions and use it!? I will try it out and accept if working, thank you!

Comment: Yeah you should be able to without issue. If you need a command line option, see my edit.

Comment: So could start the simulator once from this location but not twice. I tried to copy it and start but this gave me an error. I will try to open with command

Comment: Yeah as far as I know you can only have 1 instance of the simulator app running at one time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `xcodebuild test` to test against specific simulators. For example:

```
> xcodebuild test -project MyAppProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp -destination 'platform=Simulator,name=iPhone,OS=8.1'
```

See [Testing With Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/08-automation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH7-SW1).

Comment: The question is  not about to run a single simulator but to create one or at least use one multiple times, or did i get your answer wrong

Comment: You don't "create simulators" for iOS like Android simulators. There's one simulator application and it can emulate any recent iOS device. You can't specify the RAM, screen size, resolution, etc - you just choose which device you want to emulate, such as an iPhone 6s+. You can use the command-line to run your application on it and, when the test is done, run your application with a different device setting.

Comment: Ok, thanx for your reply. The answer again is "No", i can not run multiple devices at the same time as i asked in a performant parallel test environment. Or do you see any chance to have that. I edit my question to be more clear. I dont want a single simulator approach messing my testing time. And i want to define one device to be started multiple times to test on it. Which means i need to have those simulator instances running parallel. I dont want to wait singlethreaded for 20 test for 1 hour, i want to have them parallel.

Comment: I'm not sure if multiple simulators are supported. I tried `open -n path-to-simulator` but that produced errors. Take a look here for some possible answers: https://github.com/facebook/FBSimulatorControl

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the already accepted answer: as of Xcode 8.2 it is also possible to take screenshots using `xcrun simctl io booted screenshot` and screen video recordings with `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <filename>.<file extension>`. See also [Apple Xcode 8.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW9)